# Getting "TRUE" when RegEx doesn't match?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am attempting to try and use Regular Expressions to do a pattern match in VBA.  I've added a reference to the Regular Expression libraries and am using the following code as a test.

```
Sub testing()

Dim re
Dim val
Set re = New RegExp

re.Pattern = "[0-9]{5}"
re.IgnoreCase = True

val = Range("A8").Value

MsgBox val

MsgBox re.Test(val)

End Sub
```

The issue is that when I'm testing a string formatted as:

1234 565 4444543 12 33

I am receiving "True" when I use {5} and "False" when using {6}.  Why is this?

Shouldn't both {5} and {6} return "False" in this case?

If the RegEx is matching on the whitespace, how do I prevent this?  I want to match exactly 4 numbers followed by exactly one space followed by exactly 3 numbers, etc.

Help!

Comment: In this case, both should match, because the input contains a string of digits which is 7 digits long!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to *anchor* your regular expression:

```
re.Pattern = "^[0-9]{5}$"
```

Otherwise it matches if it finds the pattern anywhere in the input. `^` matches the beginning of the input, `$` matches the end of the input.

I'm not sure why `[0-9]{6}` returns `False` with your input, since there are 6 digits in `4444543`.